# Executar jQuery apenas uma vez quando o site e carregado

Tags: jquery, html5

Estou tendo um problema, possuo o script abaixo que toda vez que o usuário usa o browser para voltar para pagina principal esse script de animação executa.

Gostaria de saber se existe algo que eu possa fazer para ele executar apenas no primeiro acesso ao usuário, até sem refresh.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  /*ANIMAÇOES*/
  //$(".bolhasanimadas").addClass('animated slideInUp');
  $(".bolhasanimadas").addClass('animated slideInUp');
  $(".animacaoBolhas").delay(4000).slideToggle(50);
  $(".LogoAnimado").delay(800).fadeToggle(1);
  //$(".LogoAnimado").toggle( 6500 ).delay( 6500 );

  /*BARRA DE ROLAGEM*/
  setTimeout(function() {
    //$('body').css('overflow-y', 'scroll');
    $('body').addClass('barraOn');
  }, 4000);

});
```

Explicando melhor:
Na verdade esse jquery é uma animação. E eu precisaria de um script para executar essa animação apenas quando o usuário entrar no site uma vez. Depois que ele tiver navegando e por acaso dar refresh ou voltar no browser para Home e animação não irá executar novamente. Essa ideia de deixar a animação em uma index sozinha não me ajuda.

Comment: Cara, vocÊ vai ter que usar uma linguagem server side (php, asp).... 
Se for php, crie uma session na primeira vez que ele entra

Comment: Guilherme, apenas com esse script jQuery não da para reproduzir o problema, poderia complementa-lo ?

Comment: Na verdade esse jquery é uma animação.
E eu precisaria de um script para executar essa animação apenas quando o usuário entrar no site uma vez. Depois que ele tiver navegando e por acaso dar refresh ou voltar no browser para Home e animação não irá executar novamente. 
Essa ideia de deixar a animação em uma index sozinha não me ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

O document.ready é executado toda vez que a página é criada. 
O html não reconhece um postback, ou seja, quando ele volta pelo navegador tudo que estiver no document.ready será executado novamente.

Pelas descrições, parece ser uma animação na página  principal. Não sei se é, mas se for você poderia usar uma página principal que será executada uma única vez. Umá página default.html/index.html, que depois de mostrar as animações redireciona para home.html por exemplo.

Fazendo isso você estará separando a animação de entrada do seu site de sua página home. Então toda vez que o usuário voltar para página home.html ele não verá a animação novamente.

Só verá a animação na primeira vez que entrar no site.

Não sei se ficou muito claro.

Abraços.